# Highlight specific string value dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, string, nsattributedstring

Highlight words in between response dynamic data names

```
 "Work for Joy Bag is Started"
 "Work for Jack & Jill is Ended" 
 "Work for Uncle Sam is Started"
```

---

Need to highlight "Joy Bag", "Jack & Sam" and "Uncle Same" with bold and rest in regular font.

**class StudentCell: UITableViewCell**

```
var welcomeData: StudentListModel.Data?{
    didSet{
        setCellData()
    }
}

func setCellData() {
    
    if let titleValue = welcomeData?.title{
        let attributes = [[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.red], [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)]]
        nameValue.attributedText = titleValue.highlightWordsIn(highlightedWords: "Work for is Started", attributes: attributes)
    }
    
}

extension String {
    func highlightWordsIn(highlightedWords: String, attributes: [[NSAttributedString.Key: Any]]) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        let range = (self as NSString).range(of: highlightedWords)
        let result = NSMutableAttributedString(string: self)
        for attribute in attributes {
            result.addAttributes(attribute, range: range)
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

From Given String "Work for Joy Bag is Started"
In Between Work for - is Started or is Ended need to be Highlighted?

Comment: It's pretty easy to highlight everything between "Welcome" and "to" but how do you identify that **Joy** is good but **Bag** is bad?

Comment: @vadian We get response "Work for James Mond is starting"  I want to Highlight  "James Mond" word in bold and reset in regular font.

Comment: In your question you ***need to highlight Joy, Jack & Jill and Sam*** which excludes Bag and Uncle

Comment: No its will not exclude Bag & Uncle.

Comment: @vadian I updated my question.  Hope I properly written :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your code is that your calling `highlightWordsIn(highlightedWords:` with "Welcome to A B" which will never match the words you want to highlight. You need some code that will extract the substring you want to highlight, something like this using a regex (only works if the string is like on your examples):

```
if let titleValue = welcomeData?.title {
    let substringToHighlight = titleValue.matches(regex: #"(?<=^Work for )\s*+([^,]+?)(?= is (Started|Ended)$)"#).first ?? ""
    let attributes = [[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.red], [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17)]]
    nameValue.attributedText = titleValue.highlightWordsIn(highlightedWords: substringToHighlight, attributes: attributes)
}
```

Also added a method to the string extension:

```
extension String {
    func matches(regex: String) -> [String] {
        guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: []) else { return [] }
        let matches  = regex.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, self.count))
        return matches.map { match in
            return String(self[Range(match.range, in: self)!])
        }
    }
}
```

Another simpler regex to match between "for" and "is":

```
(?<=for )\s*+([^,]+?)(?= is)
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer.   I have update my question properly the word in between "for" and "is". need to be highlighted.